# javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory could not be instantiated in Websphere Application Server with Hibernate 5.2.2 Upgrade

Tags: hibernate, websphere

Upgrading Hibernate 4.2 to Hibernate 5.2 version

While deploying application in Websphere 8.5.5.13 version, throwing up following error

> 00000001 ContainerHelp E   WSVR0501E: Error creating component
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@b9dc2b3a
>   com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning:
>   com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory could not be instantiated:
>   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory: Provider
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not a subtype   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCUList(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:1303)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:275)

I tried Removing xml-api jar and maven exclusion

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

However, Web Application deployment was successful in Tomcat 9 without any changes.

Stack Trace:

```
00000001 ContainerHelp E   WSVR0501E: Error creating component com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@b9dc2b3a
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not a subtype
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCUList(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:1303)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:275)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationServerImpl.start(ApplicationServerImpl.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:540)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:702)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:407)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:170)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not a subtype
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl.join(WsComponentImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCUList(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:1295)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not a subtype
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:818)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2279)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5554)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5680)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2284)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not a subtype
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1063)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not a subtype
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.utils.XMLUtils.getDocumentBuilderFactory(XMLUtils.java:460)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.utils.XMLUtils.newDocument(XMLUtils.java:539)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.utils.XMLUtils.newDocument(XMLUtils.java:557)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.encoding.custom.Utils.loadCustomProviders(Utils.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.tools.resource.ToolEnv$3.run(ToolEnv.java:332)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.tools.resource.ToolEnv.loadCustomProviders(ToolEnv.java:329)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.tools.resource.ToolEnv.getCustomBindingProviders(ToolEnv.java:324)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.wsdl.toJava.Emitter.initCustomBindingRegistry(Emitter.java:972)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.wsdl.toJava.Emitter.setup(Emitter.java:959)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.wsdl.Parser.parse(Parser.java:326)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.wsdl.Parser.run(Parser.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.tools.WSDLQuery.parse(WSDLQuery.java:142)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.deployment.wsdd.WSDDGen.getWSDLQuery(WSDDGen.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.deployment.wsdd.WSDDPort.expand(WSDDPort.java:554)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.deployment.wsdd.WSDDPort._initTMR(WSDDPort.java:311)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.component.WSServerImpl.setupWsddPort(WSServerImpl.java:1264)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.component.WSServerImpl.warMetaDataCreated(WSServerImpl.java:2151)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.component.WSServerImpl.metaDataCreated(WSServerImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.fireMetaDataCreated(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.fireMetaDataCreated(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebMetaDataFactory.createMetaData(WebMetaDataFactory.java:244)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaDataFromFactories(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:228)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:411)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:631)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a cross-linkage between the server-level loader and a "parent last" application class loader. The server-level (actually, more likely, Java-level) loader loads the DocumentBuilderFactory API class, which then goes to the thread context class loader to find its implementation. The thread context class loader is the parent-last application loader, which does not immediately delegate to its parents, so it finds implementation there, and that in turn links to the application's copy of the API class. The original API class (from Java) and the "new" API class (from the app) cannot be cast to each other because they came from different class loaders, and the operation fails.

In terms of actually resolving this:

1) There is a 99.9% chance that you do not need to bring your own version of JAXP, which has been included in the JDK for a very long time (and it appears you're packaging Xerces, the version included in IBM Java). Removing it will eliminate that exception. Along similar lines, you could resolve this by switching to "parent first" class loader delegation - if you don't NEED to override server APIs with your own, it greatly reduces the risk of problems like this.

2) That said... you shouldn't necessarily HAVE to remove it, as the server generally allows apps to bring their own parsers. That exception stack implies that some WebSphere code may not be correctly protecting its thread context when it creates an XML object, and you may want to open a support ticket and have IBM verify whether there's an actual bug here.

Comment: Thanks Jarid for Detailed Explanation. IBM Websphere 8.5.5.13 does not support JPA 2.1. However, Hibernate 5.2.2 version requires JPA 2.1 spec. I was trying with isolated sharedlib option, which intern caused this issue. Eventually we are planning to  migrate to the WebSphere 9 to support  JPA 2.1 and to avoid jar conflicts with Parent Last Class loader policy.

Comment: Understood on the JPA 2.1 thing; however, you could just remove the XML jar(s) from the shared library and leave the JPA stuff in place. The server's built-in XML libraries should be fine with any level of JPA.

Comment: Sure Jarid, I will give a try on this option.